# Intermediate components on nested routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

As in the documentation for vue-router say I have the following rout configuration:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      component: User,
      children: [
        {
          // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/profile is matched
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

My question is about the User component. If I access /user/:id/profile followed by /user/:id/posts will the User component be render 0, 1, or 2 times?

Comment: What do you mean by "followed"? If you navigate from one page to the other? Then it won't refresh and is being reused (except when you are defining in the element or any of the parent elements the `key` attribute and whose value changes based on the navigation, e.g. $route.path).

Comment: In the browser just navigating from one route to the other. My aassumption is that the User component gets rendered with the first path (/user/:id/profile). Then if I invoke /user/:id/posts is the User component reinitialized (mounted) or does Vue somehow "know" that the User component is already rendered so in resolving the path /user/:id/posts the User component is left alone?